# Python pyqt5 My combobox not working properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I'm trying to build an app that takes information of cars using QComboBox. My combobox are filled with sql db. I create two comboboxes, the first one is for the brand name of the car, and the second one is for the name of the car of that brand, like if I choose Mercedes in the second combobox, all the cars that have Mercedes in their name will appear.

So my problem is, it prints in hex like in the third image.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

[image: Third Image]

This is my code:

```
class Add_Car(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Add_Car,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Add Car.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Add Car")
        self.MarqueCombo.addItems(self.marque_db())
        self.Modele_combo.addItems(self.Modele_db())
        

    def marque_db(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('user_data.db')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT  Marque FROM cars')
        list_of_cars = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
        conn.commit()
        conn.close
        return list_of_cars


    def Modele_db(self):
        id_us = str( self.MarqueCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.Modele_db))
        print(id_us)
        conn = sqlite3.connect("user_data.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Modéle FROM cars WHERE Marque =\''+ id_us + "\'" )
        list_of_modeles = [item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()]
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return list_of_modeles
    
    def passtt(self):
        a = self.MarqueCombo.currentText()
        print(a)

#main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
welcome=WelcomeScreen()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(welcome)
widget.setFixedHeight(590)
widget.setFixedWidth(394)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print('Exiting')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is completely wrong:

```
id_us = str( self.MarqueCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.Modele_db))
```

That is a *signal connection*. It tells that whenever the text of the `MarqueCombo` is changed, it will call `Modele_db`.
Not only it won't do what you want, but it will also create **new** connections to the functions everytime the text of the first combo changes.

What you need to do is to create the connection in the `__init__` and then (re)populate the combobox with the retrieved data from the brand combo instead.

```
class Add_Car(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(Add_Car,self).__init__()
        loadUi("Add Car.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Add Car")

        # create the connection *here*, before adding the brands
        self.MarqueCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.Modele_db)

        self.MarqueCombo.addItems(self.marque_db())

    # ...

    def Modele_db(self, id_us):
        self.Modele_combo.clear()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("user_data.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT DISTINCT Modéle FROM cars WHERE Marque =\''+ id_us + "\'" )
        self.Modele_combo.addItems([item[0] for item in cur.fetchall()])
```

<sup>Two suggestions: 1. there are few cases for which a `SELECT` requires a commit, yours is not one of them, and in any case you forgot the parentheses for `conn.close` in the first function; 2. only classes and constants should have names that begin with uppercase letters, always prefer lower case letters for functions and variables;</sup>